# WordPress: Display Post Images on Front Page

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Hoping someone can help. I've put this code into a standard template but no images are displaying, despite the fact that I've got a bunch of posts with images.

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

$images =& get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

if ( empty($images) ) {
    // no attachments here
} else {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
    }
}

endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you just need to display the images, nothing else. And are the images set as featured images

Comment: Nope, they aren't set as featured images. I only need to display images; I'm going to use Masonry and CSS to position them.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

to

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

and

```
$images =& get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));
```

to

```
$images =get_posts( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));
```

you should use get_posts()

Comment: would you `print_r($images)`

Comment: print_r will not display your images, just check by it your array contains images or not...and update your question with output of print_r($images)

Comment: Done. Now I get:

Array ( )

Comment: so you have empty array....its mean check your query post and make sure for images

Comment: I put in:

        <?php

$args = array(
 'post_type'=> 'attachment',
 'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);

query_posts( $args );

?>

Comment: http://www.vcluxe.nu/?p=27

is showing images...I don't understand why either the loop or get_posts() is not picking up the images. Maybe they are not attachments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This code will fetch all the 'large' images from the media library and display them

Hope this is what you were looking for